# ListTile: Extending subtitle bounds below trailing area

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

[image]

The above view is the result of this code:

```
    ListTile(
      leading: Container(color: Colors.blue, child: Text("leading")),
      title: Container(color: Colors.green, child: Text("title")),
      subtitle: Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text("subtitle")),
      trailing: Container(color: Colors.yellow, child: Text("trailing")),
    )
```

I am trying to extend the area for the red 'subtitle' so that it extends until the end of 'triling' but I do not want to use dirty hacks like completely removing 'trailing' and using a row.

**Update**

This is what I need:
[image]

Comment: You want to your subtitle is end of trailing?

Comment: it is not possible with `ListTile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring the docs:

> To show right-aligned metadata, consider using a [Row]
> with [CrossAxisAlignment.baseline] alignment whose first item is
> [Expanded] and whose second child is the metadata text, instead of
> using the [trailing]

I avoided using trailing. Following the advice given in the comments solved the trouble.

```
ListTile(title: Row(children: [ Expanded(main), Text('trailing') ]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding should do just fine to set bound, this way

```
ListTile(
      leading: Container(color: Colors.blue, child: Text("leading")),
      title: Container(color: Colors.green, child: Text("title")),
      subtitle: Padding(
                    //upper bound
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child:Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text("subtitle")),
                        ),
      trailing: Container(color: Colors.yellow, child: Text("trailing")),
    )
```